# Would the most logical path from Normandy to the Bavarian Alps (Germany) pass through Lyon?

Tags: france, germany, routes, identify-this

In the movie *[Edge of Tomorrow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_of_Tomorrow_(film))*, the main characters were travelling by road from Normandy in France to somewhere in the mountains of Germany (a dam)<sup>1</sup>.  During the journey, one of the characters mentions passing through Lyon, France.  Google Maps shows it thus:

1. We decided in comments to narrow it down to *"Sylvenstein (dam), about 1 hour south of Munich in the Bavarian Alps"*

[image: map]

The highlight (red marker) is on the Bavarian Alps (not the only mountains in Germany to be sure, but some of the most southern). The two stars joined by a red line represent Normandy in the north-west and Lyon in the south-east.

But.. That is heading south east, towards Italy or Switzerland, as opposed to due east, to reach Germany (their supposed destination).

The characters wanted to avoid Paris (it turns out it was heavily defended by 'the enemy' - but would probably have been expected by the characters to be unsafe to pass through even without that specific knowledge).

So, if you're at Normandy, and wish to reach the mountains (anywhere) in Germany but *avoiding Paris,* would the logical path take you through Lyon (..then presumably Switzerland)?

Comment: "...Omega hiding within a Bavarian Alps dam..." from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_of_Tomorrow_%28film%29 your dot would be about 120 km east of where you placed it, but that's fine, close enough

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/71852/why-did-the-omega-trick-william-cage-to-the-bavarian-alps-dam

Comment: In general, the problem is not so much the length of the route, but more where the road network is. In that case, France is very centralized around Paris, it means all networks (road, train, planes) go through Paris. Not literally because Paris area is big, but within 100km of Paris, probably. Then it is possible to go through Lyon (even though Dijon seems a better choice), as you can see the road network on the map. Swiss infrastructure is probably good and fast, so it sounds likely possible to follow that route.

Comment: @Vince *Then it is possible to go through Lyon (even though Dijon seems a better choice)*  I was thinking that as I perused the map. Even if they were forced to skirt south of Paris, the route seemed shorter by heading back north a little & through Dijon rather than continuing all the way to Lyon.  Though that might not be the case for the most eastern alps within Germany. *"Swiss infrastructure is probably good and fast"*  I had heard that. Perhaps it was a factor in continuing to Lyon before heading to Geneva, then through Switzerland further east and north into Germany..

Comment: The location needs to have a prominent dam and can be reached conventionally.  That would seem to narrow it down to Sylvenstein, about 1 hour south of Munich in the Bavarian Alps. But of course the entire location could be fictional.

Comment: @GayotFow *"That would seem to narrow it down to Sylvenstein, about 1 hour south of Munich in the Bavarian Alps."* Let's pin it down as that.  *"But of course the entire location could be fictional."*  The film makers were (I think) careful to go with 'plausible' locations for each part of the action, so I think that is as good a destination as any..

Comment: @GayotFow  Now I'm going to have to go back to the movie (and possibly the SciFi site) to check if there was any evidence as to why they avoided Dijon.  AFAIR there were fleeting shots of maps showing concentrations of the Mimics (the 'bad guys') - perhaps one of them showed high enemy presence in both Paris **and** Dijon.  But 'because the keys were there' .. yeah that *might* be the reason.  I have been told I tend to overthink popular movies, especially after 'threatening' to ask 22 questions about *Oblivion* (which seemed a walking plot hole, dressed with some cool bits around the edges).

Comment: @Vince  Could you upgrade your comments to an answer, including the bit about being more logical to travel via Dijon?  I think that is the best answer there is, for this question.

Comment: @GayotFow  You have certainly contributed much to the progress of the question already.  Thanks for your insights, we'll see how it goes.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Broadly, the answer to your question is 'no', there is no logic that routes the traveller through Lyon.  Assuming that the two end points are [Omaha Beach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omaha_Beach) in Normandy and the [Sylvenstein Dam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvenstein_Dam) in the Bavarian Alps, the prima facie route is Caen - Paris - Stuttgart - Munich.  It's shown below...

[image]

Even in the [fictional journey from Normandy to the Bavarian Alps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_of_Tomorrow_%28film%29), there is no reason to avoid Paris without bestowing prescience on the hero, and if the hero were prescient he wouldn't have gone to Germany in the first instance.  Moreover, the scriptwriters could have placed the helicopter in any location, Strasbourg for example.

[image]

Given that Lyon is a *ridiculously off-the-wall* route, your question (which is borderline topical by the way) raises an interesting *on-topic* question...

**Is there anything about Lyon that would prompt a film director [to pay homage to it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homage_%28arts%29)? Even if it were an homage understood by insiders only?**

Yes.  Lyon is a city that has provided the location for a many great films.  The city also has an impressive list of [notable residents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_people_from_Lyon).  Any of these might provide the grounding for an homage or [tribute](http://www.pastemagazine.com/blogs/lists/2013/02/14-allusions-to-other-movies-in-film.html).

Beyond this (or some similar outré reason), there is no "logical path" between Normandy and Sylvenstein that situates Lyon as a way-point.